# Como Cambiar la altura de mi layout programaticalmente?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una pequeña duda ..Estoy armando un item_layout para las celdas de una lista.. Existe una forma de manejar el height de las celdas, segun los datos que van cargando ...
Estoy usando

```
PercentRelativeLayout oidit;
 oidit = (PercentRelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idit);
oidit.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

para agrandar unas celdas de la lista programaticalmente ,el problema es : en una pantalla de 1080 dpi anda bien pero en pantalla mas grande como 1440 dpi o una tablet

```
oidit.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
```

no alcanzapara mostrar los restos de datos lo tengo que sumar mas dp: no 100dp pero 200 o 250 dp al height. Queria saber si hay una forma para que el valor dado adapta a cualquier pantalla?

Answer (score 2):

Crea un `LayoutParams` y configuralo a tu layout mediante  setLayoutParams() :

```
PercentRelativeLayout oidit;
oidit = (PercentRelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idit);

LayoutParams params = oidit.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;
oidit.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo logre a resolver de otra forma.. Consulte la resolucion de la patanlla en cuestion 
ojala que sirve a otro.. ahi esta mi codigo
(Estoy usando BaseAdapter...)

```
   DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display displ = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
String displayName = displ.getName();
Point size = new Point();
displ.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
int heightPixels = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int widthPixels = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
int densityDpi = displayMetrics.densityDpi;
float xdpi = displayMetrics.xdpi;
float ydpi = displayMetrics.ydpi;
int screenHeight = displ.getHeight();
int screenWidth = displ.getWidth();

if (widthPixels>=1440){
                oidit.getLayoutParams().height = 210;
            }else if(widthPixels<=1440){
                oidit.getLayoutParams().height = 100;
            }
```

Esta un poco sucio el codigo porque trae todo lo que necesita saber de tu pantalla como informacion
Ojala que le sirve a Alguien

Comment: Lo que estas realizando en realidad es lo mismo que comento, usar LayoutParams para cambiar el tamaño: LayoutParams params = oidit.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 100;
params.width = 100;

Answer (score 1):

Sé que ya es tarde para responder este hilo pero probando cosas distintas llegué a esta solución. Obtener la altura y el ancho del Layout y mordearlos a tu forma usando el valor 100dp.

Digamos que el idit tiene 400dp de altura en el xml y le queremos dar 600dp:

```
PercentRelativeLayout oidit;
oidit = (PercentRelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idit);
LayoutParams params = oidit.getLayoutParams();

//Ahora obtenemos los 400dp y los dividimos entre 4 para obtener 100dp 
//y luego los multiplicamos por 6 para obtener los 600dp.

params.height = (params.height/4)*6;
oidit.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Esto funciona para cualquier pantalla. Espero que le sirva a los que tengan aún la duda.